# carriage returns not showing in Word

Tags: php

So I am trying to create a word document using the following (yeah, don't get my started that its not the right way)

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=MyDoc.doc");
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo $myVar.PHP_EOL."test";
```

For some reason, every carriage return I have tried (I want to avoid using html tables to format) will not be recognized.  I have tried:

```
"\r\n"
Char(13).Char(10)
PHP_EOL
even </br>
```

None of them get recognized.  What am i missing to get carriage returns?

Thanks

Comment: It depends how do you inspect the output. In a browser, any amount of consecutive whitespace characters (spaces, new lines, tabs, vertical tabs etc.) is rendered as a single space. Use the `View Source` command of your browser to see how the generated HTML looks like.

Comment: look at your HTML source; they're there alright.

Comment: The web browser will not render newlines because web browsers have been doing it this way since we were in diapers. Throw in an `echo '<pre>';` after your meta tag and the newlines will render.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I think the title says that Limey is viewing it in Word.

Comment: Yes, should open in Word.  Guess i should capitalize that.  Either way, adding the pre tag worked!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware With the amount of XY Problems on this site, I assumed the lowest common denominator. Additionally the `<pre>`  tag is relevant because OP is basically opening a web page using Word so my guess is that Word kicks off an HTML rendering engine such as IE.